# need to diable Yes/No after one click on bootstrap Confirm box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i need to avoid double clicking on either YES Option or NO option, on bootstrap Confirm Box.

My box stays because i am sending ajax call behind that, so i need to stop dounle or multiple clicking on that box.

Comment: Please include all relevant code, without the code it can be very hard to help you and provide a good answer.

Comment: Mate, put some code here. Then community will be able to help more. Also, as far I remember in bootstrap 4, in modal dialog, you add your own button.

Answer (score 0):

You can add disabled attribute on one click ( Yes/No) button when you ajax call, when you got response from ajax then you just remove disabled attribute.

Comment: add class or id to bootstrap confirm box  button then do your jquery code for disable or enable button .btw show me your html  or code. then it will be more clarify.

Comment: how can i give ID to that button?

Comment: you can add id in html or in javascript you can add id using this method